# Is there a way to associate an entire class of files with an application on Windows?

Tags: windows, video, directshow, file-type-associations

I have a vanilla Windows 10 installation -- there aren't any third party video players of any kind, there is only Windows Media Player and the new Movies app. I have verified to be unable to play back, say, [WebM](https://www.webmproject.org/) (video) files.

However, I do have `.webm` Registry key under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` key, with `ContentType` value of `"video/webm"` and `PerceivedType` value of `"video"`. It's a similar situation with the other novel extensions there too, like `.webp` and `.mkv`, and others. I don't know why it's there and what created these keys.

That makes me at least believe that Windows should be capable to classify different video containers into a some sort of "video" class of files, given how it at least theoretically knows these are "video/" major MIME type each and the fact that they share the same "perceived type".

Is there a way then for me to associate all such video files with my application, without explicitly creating one association for every known video format? I want to benefit, if possible, from the kind of classification I think Windows might be able to do.

Thing is, my application doesn't explicitly support or reject individual video container formats like WebM (`.webm` extension) or MPEG-4 (`.mp4` extension), or any other -- it passes the file for playback to DirectShow, which in turn by design relies on installed filters to try and play back media files. Since these filters can be installed separately from my application, I don't see how I can reliably maintain a by-file-type association. I'd rather delegate this to whatever Windows subsystem created the `.webm` key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` key in the first place. Perhaps Microsoft updates these as part of Windows Update?

If I could associate whatever Windows considers video files, however it does so, with my application, per entire class that is video files, at least I could allow the user to attempt to play back whatever they throw at my application, by virtue of it being available in the context menu if Windows thinks it's a media file. Certainly, this is no worse than the old situation where Windows Media Player typically registers itself with a number of media container formats and still is unable to play every file of every supported format because of missing codecs. At least I won't have to update my application every time a new video format comes out.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to make it the way you want and there are objective reasons for this.

First, shell association process starts from extension to application mapping and this is a well defined process without classes of files built on top of set of extensions.

Second, there is no such thing as "video files" in first place. .mp4 and .webm are not exactly video files, because, in particular, they can hold just audio tracks and so be audio files. Media APIs start reading the files with examining container format details, identification of tracks and announcing track/stream availability for peer APIs such as codecs. That is, "video files" is not a very strict definition in first place.

Third, media APIs such as DirectShow and Media Foundation do **not** use shell association when playback is in question. Shell association and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is only in use when it comes to choosing handler application. APIs define their own method to build a pipeline for a given file, and their have their own separate collection of extension defined handlers. Then these APIs are capable to identify format of files with "wrong" extension by looking into payload data itself: if you rename .wav to .avi, the file would remain playable even though formats are different.

That is, if you want to identify a video file in your application without thinking too much about file format, why not just use one of the mentioned media APIs and open the file. If you can see through the API that the file exposes a video track then it is a video file. Even though I don't think I grasped the detail why you need to filter out video files exactly, I would probably recommend this approach.

You could probably also use shell property handlers - `PSLookupPropertyHandlerCLSID` and friends - to check if a file is a media file. Video file would report one of video related properties such as `PKEY_Video_FrameWidth`.

Then if you just need an approximate guess whether the file is a video file, you could possibly check extension against `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap` list.

Another quick method to check if it might be a video file is to check extension against API specific association list such as this `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Media Foundation\ByteStreamHandlers`. It is similar to using Media Foundation API I mentioned above but without actually using it. This registry key is where extensions are associated with API specific primitives, as opposed to shell extension associations.

Comment: Thank you Roman, some useful details in your answer! I know how to delegate playback, what I want is something like a "dynamic verb" -- a "play" verb in context menu of a given media file which is there if the container format can actually be de-multiplexed and, optionally, some/all tracks decoded. Conversely, no need to have the "play" verb in context menu if a DirectShow/WMF graph cannot be built anyway. That way I also don't have to maintain a list of supported media container formats and update my application or its installer every time a new container format comes out.

Comment: Paragraphs 2, 3, 4, and 5 in your answer did not tell me a lot of what I already did not know. Just helping you help me. I am well enough versed in DirectShow to know how playback is designed to work start to end. I am not equally proficient with WMF, though. I got a "dynamic" verb working for "video" files as classified by Windows Search / Windows Explorer (can update my question if needed) but my solution displays a "Play" verb *next* to default verb which is also called "Play" as provided by Windows Media Player.

Comment: Since we're discussing "verbs", I suppose we're talking about shell extensions. To my best knowledge you can make a shell extension which takes path and dynamically populates verb list. If in the middle of this process you could open a file and check whether it has a video track, and then if it does and there is a video track you add respective shell menu item would it be that dynamic verb you are looking for? The part of shell extension can be implemented in the described way.

Comment: I am considering to do what you have suggested. What puts me off is that I already have the "Play" option in my context menu for all "video" files that Windows Media Player at least advertises to be able to play back. If I go the shell extension route, I am afraid (have not verified) adding another "Play" menu element to the context menu is going to present user with two "Play" choices in one and the same menu. And I don't want an overly verbose "Play with Foobar" if I can avoid it -- I am against explicit application names.

Comment: With `OpenWithProgIds` I could link an extension to my ProgId where a "play" verb was defined, and only one "Play" would appear for files with said extension, choosing it wouldn't open Windows Media Player automatically anymore (as expected, perhaps), it would give the user a list of options where my application is listed with "New" under it. Pretty much exactly what I want, except I can't seem to find a way to accomplish the equivalent without having to add a registry key explicitly for every extension, past and future, that is a media container file.

Comment: If I get it right you want your app to be "default app" for video in terms of Settings, Default apps, Video player. Probably you could use procmon to find out where these settings come from. However still if standard shell associations take priority over this then it's not really useful (or insufficient)